# Could Congress make it illegal to publish compiled code without corresponding source?

Tags: united-states

Could Congress pass a law requiring publishers of compiled code to publish source as well, basically codifying the GPL except the permission to use the software (i.e. requiring all software to be source-available)? Could this be enforced against foreign publishers who make their software available in the US?

Comment: And makers of beverages like Coke to only sell drinks they have published the recipe for? And makers of integrated circuits to publish the VHDL code underlying the design or just the files for patterning the layers?

Comment: In the limit, the question boils down to - can a law be passed that forces one category of technology vendors to make their products easy to steal.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Having the Coke recipe won't let you fix a bad batch of Coke. Having VHDL code won't help you fix a broken IC. Having software source code will help you fix bugs in the software.

Comment: That is a difference.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite I'm not sure what you mean by your last comment "That is a difference."

Comment: I  acknowledge your point.

Comment: I'm with Dale that a flat mandate / ban would violate the First Amendment.  But there are plenty of other carrots and sticks that Congress could use to encourage this.  For instance, a tax credit for open source software.  Or a requirement that the federal government may only purchase or use software with publicly available source.

Comment: @NateEldredge could they say that non-source-available software is ineligible for copyright?

Comment: @Someone: That would violate the [Berne Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention) so they'd have to withdraw from that treaty first.  And because of the [TRIPS agreement](https://www.wto.org/english/docs_e/legal_e/27-trips_01_e.htm) this would also get the US kicked out of the World Trade Organization.  Then we get to First Amendment questions again because copyright protection is no longer content neutral.

Comment: @NateEldredge other than treaties, why is it okay to require disclosure of how something works for a patent but not for a copyright?

Comment: Fair question.  One possible argument would be that an invention isn't speech.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## This would fall under the Commerce Clause.

The United States Congress has the power granted to them by the US Constitution to regulate interstate commerce.

> The Congress shall have power
>
> ...
>
> To regulate Commerce with foreign Nations, and among the several States, and with the Indian Tribes;

While this clause has been abused to regulate a wide variety of things that the Founders probably didn't intend it for, regulating the interstate sale of software by requiring the source code of the software also be provided is certainly well within the intended purposes of it.

I think it's unlikely that they *would* pass such a law, but they have the power to do so if they wanted to. Similarly, the Supreme Court may or may not strike the law down as unconstitutional, but that doesn't stop Congress from passing the law in the first place.

Comment: This establishes a power under which to pass a law, but not that it is consistent with the rest of the constitution. This could easily be found to be compelled speech, for instance, or an illegal taking.

Comment: I think this might benefit from a First Amendment analysis, as well. I can see arguments on both sides, but I don't really understand the nature of the material in question well enough to come to a conclusion.

Comment: Your analysis would benefit from showing how this could pass strict scrutiny, by looking at mandatory disclosure laws where speech is compelled.

Comment: What if the software is distributed at no cost?

Comment: @Someone It's been held that Congress has the power to regulate commerce that takes place entirely within a single state because it affects interstate commerce by competing with it, so I imagine freely distributed software would also fall under the regulatory power of the commerce clause for the Sane reason.

Answer (score 2):

### Sounds like a first amendment violation to me

A law that compels speech, prima facie violation the first amendment right of freedom of speech. Such a law must survive [strict scrutiny](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_scrutiny) by demonstrating a “compelling state interest” - I don’t see one here.

Comment: Would allowing users to fix bugs in abandoned software be a compelling state interest?

Comment: @Someone There is no such thing as “abandoned software”. For as long as copyright exists, someone owns it. In any event, why should the government force people to publish what they wrote? It’s theirs, if they want to keep it private, that’s up to them. Would you like the government forcing you to publish anything and everything you wrote?

Comment: It would make sense to give copyright for quite a short time, and then extend a year for a payment X decided by the copyright holder, making damages for illegal copying 100X. (So if I pay $1000 and it’s worth $100,000 to you, you can copy it).

Comment: @DaleM by "abandoned software" I mean software where the developer does not support it anymore.  This wouldn't mean everyone who wrote software had to publish it; it would mean anyone who published the compiled code would also have to publish source code. Nobody who wasn't publishing anything would be forced to publish something.

Comment: @Someone: There's a rundown of strict scrutiny cases [here](https://www.mtsu.edu/first-amendment/article/1966/strict-scrutiny).  Compelling interests have been things like "fighting terrorism" and "preventing judicial corruption".  I wouldn't think that "helping people use old software" would make the cut.